# Не работает обратная связь ( обратный звонок )

Tags: javascript

Ошибки
 Uncaught TypeError: phone is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM2760:1353)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80&phone=%2B79854780404' from origin 'http://www.taxigreenline.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
taxigreenline.ru/phone/?name=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80&phone=%2B79854780404:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
icon-bars.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Скидываю снизу как написано. Помогите исправить

```
<h4>Заказать звонок</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="ajax_form" id="clback">
                 <div class="field">
                     <input id='name_name' type="text" name="name" required="">
                     <label  for="phone_phone">Ваше имя</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="field">
                     <input type="tel" id="phone_phone" name="phone" required="">
                     <label  for="phone_phone">Телефон</label>
                 </div>
            </div>
                 <button onclick="phone()" id='phone-button' class="submit ">Заказать обратный звонок</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="af_action" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script>

$("#phone-button").click(function() {
    phone = document.getElementById('phone_phone').value
    name = document.getElementById('name_name').value
    document.getElementById('phone-button').innerHTML = 'Отправляется диспетчеру...'
    $.get("https://taxigreenline.ru/phone/", {name:name, phone:phone})
        .done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "https://taxigreenline.ru/yes/";



        });
    });

    $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");

    $('#tel').click(function(){

        $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
    })


    $('#ghil').click(function(){

        $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').show("normal");
    })



    $('.p_close').click(function(){





        $('#popup_bg, #popphone, #popup').hide("normal");
    })



                  </script>  

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Уберите `onclick="phone()"`. Запрос на `https://taxigreenline.ru/phone?name=name&phone=123'` нельзя сделать с браузера.

Comment: onclick="phone( ) я убрал ,но все равно загрузка не происходит.

Comment: VM92:1366 Uncaught TypeError: phone is not a functione 
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM92:1366)  жалуется теперь на это. В файле прописано phone()

Comment: Нет, не убрали. Еще раз, уберите `onclick="phone()"`